# OpenCV: Use findHomography() and warpPerspective to align a bigger image onto a smaller one

Tags: python, c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

My goal is to

1. deskew a scanned image such that its text is perfectly placed on top of the text of the original image. (subtracting the images would remove the text)
2. prevent any loss of information on the deskewed image

I use SURF features to feed the findHomography function. Then I use the warpPerspective function to transform the scanned image. The resulting image almost perfectly fits onto the original image.

However, the scanned image has content on its corners which is lost after the transformation because the text in the scanned image is smaller and has to be scaled up.

[image: Original and scanned image]
<sup>*Deskewing an image that has slightly smaller text*</sup>

[image: Transformed image lost content]

<sup>*Information at the borders of the image is cropped*</sup>

To avoid any loss of information, I convert the image to RGBA and set the borderValue parameter in warpPerspective such that any added background has transparent color. I remove the transparent pixels after the transformation again. This procedure works but seems highly inefficient.

1. Question: I'm looking for a working code example (C++ or Python) that shows how to do this more efficiently.

[image: Images aren't aligned because transformed image has different dimensions]
<sup>*Image has been deskewed and content is preserved. However, the text of the two pictures isn't on top of each other anymore*</sup>

[image: Text isn't aligned anymore]

<sup>*Text position is off because the warped image has a different size than what warpPerspective expected*</sup>

After transforming the image the problem is that the two images aren't aligned anymore because the dimensions of the transformed image are different than what the warpPerspective method expected.

2. Question: How can I realign the two images? It would be great if there was a way to do incorporate this into the previous step already. Again, a working code example would be very helpful.

Here's the code that I have so far. It deskews the image while preserving its content, however, the text is not on top of the original text anymore.

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np


class Deskewer:
    def __init__(self, hessianTreshold = 5000):
        self.__hessianThresh = hessianTreshold
        self.imgOrigGray, self.imgSkewed, self.imgSkewedGray = None, None, None

    def start(self, imgOrig, imgSkewed):
        self.imgOrigGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgOrig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        self.imgSkewed = imgSkewed  # final transformation will be performed on color image
        self.imgSkewedGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgSkewed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # prior calculation is faster on gray

        kp1, des1, kp2, des2 = self.__detectFeatures()
        goodMatches = self.__flannMatch(des1, des2)

        MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
        M = None
        if len(goodMatches) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
            M, _ = self.__findHomography(kp1, kp2, goodMatches)
        else:
            print("Not  enough  matches are found   -   %d/%d" % (len(goodMatches), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
            return

        return self.__deskew(M)


    def __detectFeatures(self):
        surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(self.__hessianThresh)
        kp1, des1 = surf.detectAndCompute(self.imgOrigGray, None)
        kp2, des2 = surf.detectAndCompute(self.imgSkewedGray, None)

        return kp1, des1, kp2, des2

    def __flannMatch(self, des1, des2):
        global matches
        FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
        index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
        search_params = dict(checks=50)
        flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
        matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

        # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
        good = []
        for m, n in matches:
            if m.distance < 0.7 * n.distance:
                good.append(m)

        return good

    def __findHomography(self, kp1, kp2, goodMatches):
        src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in goodMatches
                              ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in goodMatches
                              ]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
        matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()
        i = matchesMask.index(1)

        # TODO: This is a matching point before the warpPerspective call. How can I calculate this point AFTER the call?
        print("POINTS: object(", src_pts[i][0][1], ",", src_pts[i][0][0], ") - scene(", dst_pts[i][0][1], ",", dst_pts[i][0][0], ")")

        return M, mask

    def getComponents(self, M):
        # ((translationx, translationy), rotation, (scalex, scaley), shear)
        a = M[0, 0]
        b = M[0, 1]
        c = M[0, 2]
        d = M[1, 0]
        e = M[1, 1]
        f = M[1, 2]

        p = math.sqrt(a * a + b * b)
        r = (a * e - b * d) / (p)
        q = (a * d + b * e) / (a * e - b * d)

        translation = (c, f)
        scale = (p, r)  # p = x-Axis, r = y-Axis
        shear = q
        theta = math.atan2(b, a)
        degrees = math.atan2(b, a) * 180 / math.pi

        return (translation, theta, degrees, scale, shear)

    def __deskew(self, M):
        # this info might come in handy here for calculating the dsize of warpPerspective?
        translation, theta, degrees, scale, shear = self.getComponents(M)

        # Alpha channel allows me to set unique feature to pixels that are created during warpPerspective
        imSkewedAlpha = cv2.cvtColor(self.imgSkewed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)

        # These sizes have been randomly choosen to make sure that all the contents fit in the new canvas
        height = 5000
        width = 5000
        shift = -500

        M2 = np.array([[1, 0, shift],
                      [0, 1, shift],
                      [0, 0, 1]])
        M3 = np.dot(M, M2)

        # TODO: How can I calculate the dsize argument?
        # Newly created pixels are set to transparent
        im_out = cv2.warpPerspective(imSkewedAlpha, M3,
                                     (height, width), flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(255, 0, 0, 0))

        # http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/132933
        # Mask of non-black pixels (assuming image has a single channel).
        mask = im_out[:, :, 3] == 255

        # Coordinates of non-black pixels.
        coords = np.argwhere(mask)

        # Bounding box of non-black pixels.
        x0, y0 = coords.min(axis=0)
        x1, y1 = coords.max(axis=0) + 1  # slices are exclusive at the top

        # Get the contents of the bounding box.
        cropped = im_out[x0:x1, y0:y1]

        # TODO: The warped image needs to align nicely on the original image
        return cropped

origImg = cv2.imread("Letter.png")
skewedImg = cv2.imread("A4.png")
deskewed = Deskewer().start(origImg, skewedImg)
cv2.imshow("Original", origImg)
cv2.imshow("Deskewed", deskewed)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Original image for testing]
[image: Skewed image for testing]
<sup>*Original and skewed image (with additional content) for testing*</sup>

Comment: Can you upload a sample image? And how do you want it transformed? It would give better clarity to the question.